# Menu icons not correct in Inkscape

Tags: 18.04, icons, inkscape

I have installed **inkscape** (0.92.3-1) on Ubuntu 18.04, and everything works fine.

However, the icon panel (tools panel) on the left side doesn't show the icons in a correct manner!

Thankful for any  solution

[image: inkscape]

Comment: What's your icon theme and application theme?

Comment: I've **MacOsx Icon Theme** - when I switch back to  Adwaita it's ok.  pomsky: Thanks, have to modify the icon theme.

Comment: Using a dark variant of an application theme would also probably work.

Comment: I use the **Sierra dark** theme.  I got  it now - I've used McOSX-dark icons instead of the MacOSX icons. thx

Answer (score 0):

Simple changing the **icon type ** in your desktop settings does the job.